# How to pass a value (any variable) to the search box(Google) in Robot Framework Automation While Running (Through Command Line)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

My Code is Given Below...
NB:This is a simple Google search program.

```
*** settings ***  
Library   SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***  
${browser}    Chrome  
${url}    https://google.com

*** Test Cases ***  
Google Index    

     Go To google

*** Keywords ***  
Go To google  
    
    open browser   ${url}    ${browser}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    //input[@title='Search']        60
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    //input[@title='Search']    50
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Press Keys   //input[@title='Search']    ***Hello_World***
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Press Keys   None   RETURN
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Sleep  2s
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    //a[@id='logo']    25
    Close browser
```

The Above Code is working Fine. But I Need to Change the Value (Hello_World) and I need to replace that value with a value that I can pass while running the robot file.

I've gone through Some sites, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Robot Framework has Dialogs library that has keywords for getting user input: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

You can [pass the definition of variables on the command line](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-variables-in-command-line) with the `--variable` option.

First, modify the test case to look like this:

```
Go To google    
    ...
    Press Keys   //input[@title='Search']    ${search_string}
    ...
```

Next, pass the search string as an argument on the command line:

```
$ robot --variable search_string:Hello_World
```